# Edit urls in wagtail (social-auth-app-django problems)

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to add [social-auth-app-django](https://www.google.com/search?q=social-auth-app-django&oq=social-auth-app-django&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l4.786j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to my wagtail project to let normal users comment posts on blog. To make social-auth-app-django work, I need to add this urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),  
]
```

How to do it? I didn't find any way to edit urls.py in wagtail, and I didn't find any social-auth-app-django wagtail equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a `urls.py` in the folder where `settings.py` will also be present.

Add the URL in `urlpatterns` list present in the `urls.py` like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),  
]
```

Comment: Note that this URL pattern needs to be placed above the existing `url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),` line, so that it takes precedence over being handled as a Wagtail page.